# Join without on sql

Tags: sql

For example, I have a table T1 that has two columns A and B. I want to write a sql query that get the result of `COUNT(A)/COUNT(DISTINCT C)`, column C is a new column derived from column B.

```
┌┄┄┄┄┄┬┄┄┄┄┄┬       ┄┄┄┄┐
┆  A  ┆  B  ┆         C ┆
├┄┄┄┄┄┆┄┄┄┄┄┆       ┄┄┄┄┤
┆  1  ┆  1  ┆        1b ┆
├┄┄┄┄┄┆┄┄┄┄┄┆       ┄┄┄┄┆
┆  2  ┆  2  ┆        2b ┆
├┄┄┄┄┄┆┄┄┄┄┄┆       ┄┄┄┄┤
┆  3  ┆  2  ┆        2b ┆
└┄┄┄┄┄┴┄┄┄┄┄┴       ┄┄┄┄┘
```

Here is what I think:

```
SELECT COUNT(A)/COUNT(DISTINCT C)

FROM T1 (?) (SELECT CAST(B, varchar)+'b' AS C FROM T1)
```

I haven't found a type of JOIN that can combine T1 and column C into a table like below:

```
┌┄┄┄┄┄┬┄┄┄┄┄┬┄┄┄┄┄┐
┆  A  ┆  B  ┆  C  ┆
├┄┄┄┄┄┆┄┄┄┄┄┆┄┄┄┄┄┤
┆  1  ┆  1  ┆  1b ┆
├┄┄┄┄┄┆┄┄┄┄┄┆┄┄┄┄┄┆
┆  2  ┆  2  ┆  2b ┆
├┄┄┄┄┄┆┄┄┄┄┄┆┄┄┄┄┄┤
┆  3  ┆  2  ┆  2b ┆
└┄┄┄┄┄┴┄┄┄┄┄┴┄┄┄┄┄┘
```

What should I do? Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Like that?

```
SELECT COUNT(A) * 1.0 / COUNT(DISTINCT C)
FROM (SELECT A, CAST(B, varchar)+'b' AS C FROM T1)
```

The inner query gets for each row a value of `A` and a modified value of corresponding `B`

```
Inner:
┌┄┄┄┄┄┬┄┄┄┄┄┬
┆  A  ┆  C  ┆
├┄┄┄┄┄┆┄┄┄┄┄┆
┆  1  ┆  1b ┆
├┄┄┄┄┄┆┄┄┄┄┄┆
┆  2  ┆  2b ┆
├┄┄┄┄┄┆┄┄┄┄┄┆
┆  3  ┆  2b ┆
└┄┄┄┄┄┴┄┄┄┄┄┴
```

The outer query finds what you're looking for (using the mentioned by [Gordon](https://stackoverflow.com/a/61749697/8564999) decimal trick)

Comment: Thank you. If there is another condition when selecting A ( e.g. only select value 2 and 3). Can I add a WHERE clause at the end like "WHERE A IN (2, 3)"?

Comment: Yes, add it in the inner query. The outer query is executed after the inner one.

Answer (score 1):

You seem to be describing:

```
SELECT COUNT(A) * 1.0 / COUNT(DISTINCT C)
FROM T1
```

From what I can tell, your database does integer division, so 3/2 = 1 rather than 1.5.  The `* 1.0` turns the integers into decimals so the truncation does not happen.

Comment: YES. Thanks, I have deleted the expected output value. Because the output value isn't important.